# How should we promote this site?

Tags: discussion

Continuing the discussion from [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/how-can-we-ensure-a-healty-beta-for-the-economics-se) and [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/interstack-trade-and-the-inefficiency-of-autarky), let's keep this as a master list of suggestions.

Comment: I've just created the meta-tag [meta-tag:7-essential-questions] - would you like to add it to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Find places where economics experts post, and post links from there to context-relevant Q&A here. So if we've got a good Q&A on a particular market failure, and that comes up in discussion somewhere, then post a link there back to the Q&A here. Use the "share" link under a question or answer to post a link that's unique to you: that way, you can earn [bronze](https://economics.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer), [silver](https://economics.stackexchange.com/badges/60/booster) and [gold](https://economics.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist) badges for pulling in traffic.  Don't spam: just share our quality content in a sensitive, thoughtful and helpful way.

And it can often help avoid misunderstandings, when linking to content here, to mention that we're not a forum, we're a Q&A site, and so we work differently to forums.